# Combining various lines in a long .txt in python

Tags: python, html, regex, newline

I have a problem with a transformation of a word-exported-html-file. I needed to get the text of an .doc-file with all the style infos (bold, italics...). The tag-cleaner in my code works well and now i have a result.txt with just the tags.

The problem now is, that the html-export split lines where it shouldn't. He might put \n between a single line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <TITLE>19</TITLE>
    <META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="OpenOffice 4.1.3  (Unix)">
    <META NAME="AUTHOR" CONTENT="IGM">
    <META NAME="CREATED" CONTENT="20160425;12590000">
    <META NAME="CHANGEDBY" CONTENT="Arno Michalowski">
    <META NAME="CHANGED" CONTENT="20160425;13460000">
    <META NAME="SDFOOTNOTE" CONTENT=";;;;C">
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    <!--
        @page { margin-right: 3.6cm; margin-top: 2.4cm; margin-bottom: 3.4cm }
            P { margin-left: 2cm; text-indent: -2cm; margin-bottom: 0.21cm; direction: ltr; color: #000000; line-height: 0.49cm; text-align: justify; widows: 2; orphans: 2 }
            P.western { font-family: "Times", serif; font-size: 12pt; so-language: de-DE }
            P.cjk { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 12pt }
            P.ctl { font-family: "Times", serif; font-size: 10pt; so-language: ar-SA }
            P.sdfootnote-western { margin-left: 3cm; text-indent: -1cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-family: "Times", serif; font-size: 10pt; so-language: de-DE; line-height: 0.42cm; text-align: left }
            P.sdfootnote-cjk { margin-left: 3cm; text-indent: -1cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 0.42cm; text-align: left }
            P.sdfootnote-ctl { margin-left: 3cm; text-indent: -1cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-family: "Times", serif; font-size: 10pt; so-language: ar-SA; line-height: 0.42cm; text-align: left }
            A.sdfootnoteanc { font-size: 57% }
            A.sdfootnotesym-western { font-family: "Times", serif; font-size: 10pt }
        A.sdfootnotesym-cjk { font-size: 10pt }
        A.sdfootnotesym-ctl { font-family: "Times", serif }
 -->
 </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY LANG="en" TEXT="#000000" DIR="LTR">
<DIV TYPE=HEADER>
    <P LANG="de-DE" ALIGN=CENTER STYLE="margin-bottom: 0.9cm"><SDFIELD TYPE=PAGE SUBTYPE=RANDOM FORMAT=PAGE>184</SDFIELD></P>
</DIV>
<P LANG="de-DE" ALIGN=RIGHT STYLE="margin-left: 0.3cm; text-indent: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.42cm">
<FONT FACE="Courier, monospace"><FONT SIZE=2><SPAN STYLE="font-weight: normal"> </SPAN></FONT></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US"><SPAN STYLE="font-weight: normal">19</SPAN></SPAN></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Courier, monospace"><FONT SIZE=2><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></FONT></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">1  </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><B><SPAN LANG="en-US">M</SPAN></B></I></FONT><SUP><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><FONT SIZE=2><I><B><SPAN LANG="en-US">r</SPAN></B></I></FONT></FONT></SUP><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><B><SPAN LANG="en-US">.
Bavoil</SPAN></B></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Courier, monospace"><FONT SIZE=2><SPAN LANG="en-US">
</SPAN></FONT></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">-
56 ans - clincailler au quai au</SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">[</SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">x</SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">]</SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">
fleur</SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">[</SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">s</SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">]</SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">
-</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Courier, monospace"><FONT SIZE=2><SPAN LANG="en-US"><I> </I></SPAN></FONT></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">2   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">100
toujours l'ouïe</SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">°</SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">
dure</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Courier, monospace"><FONT SIZE=2><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></FONT></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">3 </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><B><SPAN LANG="en-US"> 26
mai</SPAN></B></I></FONT><SUP><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><FONT SIZE=2><A CLASS="sdfootnoteanc" NAME="sdfootnote1anc" HREF="#sdfootnote1sym"><SUP>1</SUP></A></FONT></FONT></SUP><FONT FACE="Courier, monospace"><FONT SIZE=2><SPAN LANG="en-US"><I>
</I></SPAN></FONT></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">-
l'oreille droite jette du pus depuis 6 ou 8 mois - ce mois</SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">[</SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">-</SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">]</SPAN></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Courier, monospace"><FONT SIZE=2><SPAN LANG="en-US"><I> </I></SPAN></FONT></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">4   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">ci
encore plus - surdité de cette oreille depuis 2 mois</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">5   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">il
a eu un coup d'air en route - depuis 15 ans il a eu</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">6   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">l'oreille
dure alternativement l'une et l'autre -</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">7   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">maintenant
alternativement aussi</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">8   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">douleur
</SPAN></I></FONT><SUP><FONT FACE="Courier New, monospace"><SPAN LANG="en-US">┌</SPAN></FONT></SUP><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">dans</SPAN></I></FONT><SUP><FONT FACE="Courier New, monospace"><SPAN LANG="en-US">┐</SPAN></FONT></SUP><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">
sur l'os externe du coude il ne peut rien lever en</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">9   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">ayant
la main tournée en dedans -</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">10   </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US">dort,
mange bien</SPAN></I></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><I><SPAN LANG="en-US"> </SPAN></I></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US">11   avant
6 semaines de l'onguent de tart.em. derrière l[']oreille </SPAN></FONT>
</P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US"> 12   qui
lui poussait de boutons très dou-</SPAN></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US"> 13   loureux
et causait un fièvre°</SPAN></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US"> 14   n'entend
point du tout ma montre d'or à droit[e]</SPAN></FONT></P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US"> 15   mais
à la gauche en 8 pouce de distance </SPAN></FONT>
</P>
<P LANG="de-DE" CLASS="western" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Times, serif"><SPAN LANG="en-US"> 9 *  Tinctura
Sulph. </SPAN></FONT><FONT FACE="Times, serif">1 globule C 30 en 14
C. 1 Spiritus vini</FONT></P>
```

[The want-to file should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFkbm.png). But keep in mind, that i now have tags with all the bold and italics informations. It's just about the linebreaks and where they are.

Every line should start with \t\d and ends with a linebreak. But because of that shitty export, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUWh9.png).

How can i combine all the lines that doesn't start with \t\d with the first one that starts with \t\d?

I wanted to use re.sub but i think i messed up with the regex. I tried something like this. My python skill is unfortunately not that good, im an Digital Humanist.

```
regex1 = r"(^\t\d.*?)\n(.*?)\n"
final = re.sub(regex1, "\2\1\n", f)
```

Isn't there a faster way just to delete all the not wanted \n?

Thanks so much for the help. Any code is appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the original text has about 1000 pages in the .doc. And we have more files to go. Thats why we should solve it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `"\n"` with `""` when not followed by `\t\d` is easy with a regex lookahead.

```
final = re.sub(r'\n(?!\t\d)', '', f)
```

The negative lookahead `(?!subregex)` forces the regex engine to skip a match if the text immediately after the ostensible match matches `subregex` in the lookahead.

Comment: thanks a lot. that might solve my problem. im gonna try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all your HTML in a variable called, say, `mess`, you could simply do a

```
mess.replace("\n","")
```

Comment: then i would replace all the \n. But i need them. It's just about the \n that doesnt come before \t\d

Comment: @fabsurd I understand. While I cannot look into the specific problem now, [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) should be able to help you out. I'll check back in again a few hours later and get to it if it hasn't been solved by then.

Comment: that looks amazing. i have to check it out!